# Style attribute returns different values for IE and Firefox consoles

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have a `div` which has different styles at different time during execution.
While I try to read the value of the style in my JS, I get different results in different browsers.

IE : `"DISPLAY: inline;"`
Firefox: `"display: none;"`
Chrome: `"display: none;"`

Chrome and Firefox give the same result but IE has a different. How do I make it work for the all the browsers ?
Is this fixable ?
I have to read this attribute and depending on the condition do my calculation .

Comment: Can you provide us a fiddle demo, it be helpful.

Comment: Do you use some kind of css reset on the page ? If not try to include that first as it normalizes the differences between browsers/platforms..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much code to see, but a good guess would be, that a script has set `div.runtimeStyle.display = 'none'`. Setting [`runtimeStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't reflect to the values of `style` object, the effect can be seen only on the screen.

(For some reason `display` can't be found from the property list at the linked page, `runtimeStyle.display` works though.)

Another alternative is, that you retrieve the value of `style` using [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object immediately after `display: none` has been set (for example jQuery uses this object if `getComputedStyle()` doesn't exist (IE<9)). `currentStyle` is updated asynchronously, and may not have been updated at the time you're reading the value.

A probable code causing the issue in IE<9:

```
console.log($('#div').css('display', 'none').css('display'));
```